# Sharepoint/site home page without site header

Tags: custom, site, homepage, header

Is there some way to create a homepage/portal/hub/landingpage and not have the site header/titlebar show up?

We would like to create a single page containing all kinds of useful info without the user having to scroll down. So we'd like to be able to customise the page starting right beneath the sharepoint/office 365 header (containing the waffle).

I am finding a lot of different answers and hacks but I haven't found a way that works. But I'm starting to doubt if it's even possible at all.

Or can I just create my own html page somewhere inside of Office 365 and from there link to Sharepoint?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: commented this below.

I want to get rid of the "site" title . The pagetitle is already gone as I'm trying to use a homepage as base, not a normal page (which does have a seperate page title header but the homepage doesn't) edit: I'm going to try if removing the ElementID pageTitle does the trick. ElementID pageTitle contains the name of the site. ElementID pageContentTitle contains the name of the page. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I want to get rid of the "site" title . The pagetitle  is already gone as I'm trying to use a homepage as base, not a normal page (which does have a seperate page title header but the homepage doesn't)

edit: I'm going to try if removing the ElementID pageTitle does the trick. ElementID pageTitle contains the name of the site. ElementID pageContentTitle contains the name of the page. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're using classic site pages.

If you're using Office 365, the new modern site pages are in the process of a [wave of updates](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-SharePoint-Blog/SharePoint-page-enhancements/ba-p/334735), including customizing the title region that you're describing, which should be publicly available at the end of the month.  If you're not using one yet, I'd recommend creating a new Communications site to utilize the modern tooling and features.  Do this from your Sharepoint landing page/create site.  Creating one through the classic admin panel gets you a classic site.

If you're using classic pages, add a snippet/content editor web part to the bottom of the page and insert the following CSS:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
﻿#pageContentTitle { 
display:none !important; 
} 
</style>
```